# Does changing the order of integration work here?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I've sketched the region $D$, and decided to change the order of integration so that the inner integral has boundaries of $x^2 < y < 1$ and the outer integral has boundaries of $0 < x < 1$. However, I keep ending up with an integral of $\frac1{2+x^3}$ which's quite problematic to solve for. I was wondering if there's any other more efficient way to solve it, in case I'm not getting something wrong.

Comment: Yes, changing the order of integration will lead to an easy calculation

Comment: Inner integral has bounds $0 \leq y \leq x^2$.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe How that ? I do not see how to avoid the $\frac{1}{2+x^3}$-expression

Comment: Unless I'm making a mistake, the area $\int dA$ is the under the parabola $y=x^2,x\in [0,1]$. By changing the order, we have $$\int_\limits{0}^1\int_\limits{0}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2+x^3}dydx$$The inner integral will give us an $x^2$ term in the numerator.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks everyone! I made a silly mistake with changing the boundaries